# How to sum data field(s) for records with duplicate Key1 Key2 pairs, and end up with records with unique Key1 Key2 pairs

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum, duplicates, key

Given a dataframe with an unspecified number of records with duplicate key1 & key2 pairs, but not necessarily the same data.  (I.e. The combination of Key1 and Key2 is non-unique.)
I need to add the respective data columns for the duplicated records and end up with records that have unique key1 & key2 values.
I've scoured the web, but all I can find is posts about deleting duplicate records, and I don't have duplicate records, I have records with duplicate key1 & key2 pairs.

The following code should simplify and illustrate what I’m looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'key1':[1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2],'key2':[2,2,1,2,2,4,2,2],'data':[5,6,2,6,1,6,2,8]}

frame=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['key1','key2','data'])

print frame

     key1  key2  data

0     1     2     5

1     2     2     6

2     3     1     2

3     1     2     6

4     2     2     1

5     3     4     6

6     2     2     2

7     2     2     8
```

Records 0 and 3 have duplicate Key1 and Key2 pairs “1” & “2”

Records 1, 4, 6, and 7 have duplicate key1 and key2 pairs “2” & “2”

I need to end up with the following: (all key1 & Key2 pairs unique, data summed)

```
     key1  key2  data
0     1     2    11     (11 = 5+6, sum of data from Records 0 and 3)

1     2     2     17    (17 = 6+1+2+8, sum of data from Records 1, 4, 6, and 7)

2     3     1     2

3     3     4     6
```

Comment: `frame.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])['data'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Wow, now that's a work of art!  I ended up using:

frame=frame.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])['data'].sum().reset_index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as MaxU said, you could use `groupby` and then the `sum()` method such has:

```
frame.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])['data'].sum().reset_index()
Out[12]: 
   key1  key2  data
0     1     2    11
1     2     2    17
2     3     1     2
3     3     4     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for aggregating [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) with parameter `as_index=False` - `reset_index` is not necessary:

```
print (frame.groupby(['key1', 'key2'], as_index=False)['data'].sum())
   key1  key2  data
0     1     2    11
1     2     2    17
2     3     1     2
3     3     4     6
```

Comment: Thanks, but your sample looks cleaner than mine, so I ended up keeping the .reset_index()

Comment: @MikeF. - it is up to you. Both solution works perfectly. Nice day!